# Validation null Curly brackets json - Android

Tags: android, android-json, gson

I am getting a `json` like bellow from service :

```
[
    {
        "commentID": 21,
        "commentAuthor": "AAA",
        "commentText": "BBB",
        "commentDate": 1484824835,
        "productName": "XXXXX",
        "productUrl": "xxx.html",
        "productPictureUrl": "yyy.jpg"
    } ,
{
        "commentID": 21,
        "commentAuthor": "AAA",
        "commentText": "BBB",
        "commentDate": 1484824835,
        "productName": "XXXXX",
        "productUrl": "xxx.html",
        "productPictureUrl": "yyy.jpg"
    }
]
```

I get above `json` with `retrofit` and `Gson`.

`Problem` : When the `json` is empty like bellow how I can validation it ?

```
[{}]
```

I get values of `json` with `Gson` like bellow :

```
RetrofitApi.getVendorAdminApi()
        .getComments(userToken, pageNumber)
        .enqueue(new Callback<List<Comment>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Comment>> call, Response<List<Comment>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    resultListener.onSuccess(response.body());
                } else {
                    resultListener.onFailure();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Comment>> call, Throwable t) {
                resultListener.onFailure();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why does your web service want to return `[{}]` rather than `[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, I think [Gson omits null fields](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#null-object-support).

Therefore, `{}` would be the same as

```
{
    "commentID": null,
    "commentAuthor": null,
    "commentText": null,
    "commentDate": null,
    "productName": null,
    "productUrl": null,
    "productPictureUrl": null
}
```

Which, if you defined a `new Comment()`, and compared it against `response.body().get(0)`, it should be equal.

Note: this requires you to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in `Comment.java`

Comment: I edited [{}] to [] and good work but above code is true too .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> [{}] // Wrong

Rectify your Response from server. It would be

> [] // Perfect

You should check  **Json Array** **SIZE**

```
if (JsonOBJ.size()==0) 
 {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Json Is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

**Edit**

```
 if (JsonOBJ.entrySet().size()==0) 
 {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Json Is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: I am using from Gson for get json but I don't have JsonOBJ ?

Comment: I just have JsonObject.

Comment: @JoJoRoid whenever you get the responce check size

Comment: I get size : response.body().size() but get me 1 and it is not 0 !

Comment: @JoJoRoid `response.body()` is a list. If there is any object, even if empty, in it, then yes, it'll have 1 size

Comment: @cricket_007 What can I do ?

Comment: @JoJoRoid Not much because you have a valid `Comment` object with all null fields... You could make some static `NULL_COMMENT` object and implement a proper `Comment.equals()` method

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for sharing knowledge